# Error 70104 POM_start_not_yet_called while patching Teamcenter from 9.1.0 to 9.1.2.8

Tags: patch, teamcenter

I have Teamcenter 9.1.0 and I am patching it to 9.1.2.8.

During the installation I am getting the following error:

```
Executing ["generate_metadata_cache"  -u=infodba -p=***** -g=dba -force]
Output from command:  "generate_metadata_cache"  -u=infodba -p=***** -g=dba -force
Error allocating Teamcenter user license
Command line login fail! Error code = 70104 (POM_start_not_yet_called)
command_exit=70104
Exit Status  70104, elapsed time 0:00:08
```

It was suggested to run the following utility:

```
generate_metadata_cache -u=infodba -p=***** -g=dba -force
```

While I was running that command I again got the error:

```
Command line login fail! Error code = 70104 (POM_start_not_yet_called)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your Teamcenter should be connected to License Server, you cannot launch teamcenter utilities without connecting to license server

Answer (score 0):

Error 70104 is

```
Error allocating Teamcenter user license
```

so probably, you don't have enough licenses but you are doing it using infodba.
so your license server may be down or utility not able to connect to license.

if you check your log file, it would reveal.

Answer (score 0):

This is because probably your license server might be an older version than it is required. Try to download the newest version and it might work.